# MATLAB: interpolate vector

Tags: matlab

How can I interpolate a vector in MATLAB?

For example, I have the following matrix:

```
M=    
 1 10  
 2 20  
 3 30  
 4 40
```

The first column of `M` denotes the independent parameter of `x` coordinate while the second column of `M` denotes the output or `y` coordinate.

I also have the following input vector:

```
a =
 2.3  
 2.1  
 3.5
```

For each value of `a`, I wish to determine what the output interpolated result would be.  In this case, given `a`, I wish to return

```
23   
21   
35
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's the answer to the question after the edit, i.e. "how to interpolate"

You want to use [interp1](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/interp1.html)

```
M = [1 10;2 20;3 30;4 40];
a = [2.3;2.1;3.5;1.2];

interpolatedVector = interp1(M(:,1),M(:,2),a)
interpolatedVector =
    23
    21
    35
    12
```

---

Here's the answer to the question "find the two closest entries in a vector", i.e. the original question before the edit.

```
x=[1,2,3,4,5]'; %'#
a =3.3;

%# sort the absolute difference
[~,idx] = sort(abs(x-a));

%# find the two closest entries
twoClosestIdx = idx(1:2);

%# turn it into a logical array
%#   if linear indices aren't good enough
twoClosestIdxLogical = false(size(x));
twoClosestIdxLogical(twoClosestIdx) = true;
twoClosestIdxLogical =
     0
     0
     1
     1
     0
```

Comment: thanks bro, sorry to edit the question on you like that. i was trying to solve the first question in order to solve the second, but i did not matlab had a build in function that does this

Comment: Matlab has a built in function to do almost anything. Always check out the documentation before re-inventing the wheel. Matlab documentation is some of the best documentation I have ever seen for anything ever.

Comment: Mathworks ought to sponsor SO, because now you can actually discover the built-in functions you need.

Comment: @EvgeniSergeev - That's pretty funny.  Almost all of the functions I learned how to use in MATLAB I learned through SO.