# Matlab Interpolation of an Array

Tags: arrays, matlab, interpolation

Using the array below:

```
-2,  0
-1,  0.1
 0,  0.4
 2,  0.6
 3,  0.9
 5,  1
```

I need to be able to interpolate it using a function in MatLab to find out what values of `x` correspond to `y = 0.06, 0.13, 0.58`

Comment: Is the left column x values and the right y values?

Comment: do `help interp1` in Matlab

Comment: As one of a million, not to mention the documentation itself: possible duplicate of [MATLAB: interpolate vector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987142/matlab-interpolate-vector)

Answer (score 1):

It is as simple as that:

```
A = [-2,  0;
     -1,  0.1;
      0,  0.4;
      2,  0.6;
      3,  0.9;
      5,  1  ]

yi = [0.06, 0.13, 0.58]
```

and then:

[**`xi = interp1(A(:,2),A(:,1),yi)`**](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html)

returns:

```
xi =

   -1.4000   -0.9000    1.8000
```

you could have found out that by yourself ;)

Answer (score 1):

The function you are looking for is [`interp1`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html). You can use it in two forms, if you want linear interpolation then you can simply use:

```
x  = [0,0.1,0.4,0.6,0.9];
v  = [-2,-1,0,2,3,5];
xq = [0.06,0.13,0.58];
vq = interp1(x,v,xq);
```

Resulting with

```
vq =

   -1.4000   -0.9000    1.8000
```

If you want a different type of interpolation, you put the type you want as the 4<sup>th</sup> parameter:

```
vq = interp1(v,x,xq,'PCHIP');
```

Resulting with

```
vq =

   -1.3185   -0.8534    1.8695
```

The available interpolation methods are: `nearest`, `linear`,`spline`,`pchip` and `cubic`.