# Matlab resampling vectors

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector

I'm currently trying to find a way to resample vectors. So for example if I have a vector of size 4 `[1 3 5 7]` and I want to shrink it to size 3 it would give me `[1 4 8]` or something like that. Same for enlarging but in the opposite way.

I have searched and found the function **Interp** and **Decimate**, which actually do this, but the problem is that I don't have an integer enlarging or shrinking factor. I have vectors of size 140 to 160 and I want them all to be of size 150. This can't be done with **Interp** or **Decimate** because they only work with integer factors.

So I'm wondering, is there any fast way to do this or do I actually have to think of a clever way to do this reshaping?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `interp1` can do that. Also you should clarify what you actually want. You are not *enlarging* and *shrinking*, but resampling. And after you have resampled you won't be able to get back your original...

Comment: But interp doesn't accept a non-integer number as enlarging or shrinking factor, or am I not using Interp the correct way? Because I use it as interp(A,150/140)

Comment: `interp1` does not accept a scaling or shrinking factor.  You have to specify the points that you want to interpolate at yourself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MATLAB: interpolate vector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987142/matlab-interpolate-vector)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you would like to **resample** a data vector.  What you can do is use [`interp1`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html) in MATLAB, but you specify a range of points from the beginning of where you want to sample to the end, and the number of points within this range is the total number of points for your desired output.

To accomplish what you want, use [`linspace`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linspace.html).  In addition, you would use the array you want to resample as the **output** or `y` values, and you would use **dummy** `x` values that are defined for each value in the array you are trying to resample.  Something simple like `x = [1 2 ... ]` up to as many elements as there are in your vector would work.

Working with your small example, do this:

```
a = [1 3 5 7];
x = 1 : numel(a);
xp = linspace(x(1), x(end), 3); %// Specify 3 output points
y = interp1(x, a, xp)

y =

     1     4     7
```

Therefore, for your specific case, change the third line of your code so that `3` is changed to `150`.  Defining `a` is up to you, but the second line of code and last line of code should stay the same.

The advantage of the above approach is that the data vector is not assumed to be increasing or decreasing.  In fact, it can be all random.  What should happen is that your data (stored in `a`) will be resampled given your desired number of points.

Comment: @CrazyRat - I agree :).  +1 for you too.  What you did with `linspace` gets more to the point than what I did.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you have the image processing toolbox i would use

```
new_vector = imresize(old_vector, ratio);
```

**edit**

There is one actual issue I just noticed. If ratio > 1 the result is no longer a vector but a matrix. Its easy enough to solve since every row is the same (this also works if ratio <=1 so its always safe to use)

```
new_vector = imresize(old_vector, ratio);
new_vector = new_vector(1,:);
```

or a bit more elegant (credit goes to 2cents)

```
new_vector  = imresize(old_vector , [desired_num_rows desired_num_cols])
```

Comment: You don't have to normalize the data to `[0,1]` if the input is `double` for `imresize`.  That's unnecessary.  Try it on: `B = imresize([1 2; 3 4], 2);`.  You'll see that the output is linearly interpolated by expanding the 2 x 2 input matrix by a factor of 2, and all of the data is floating point and not within `[0,1]`, so you can remove that normalization step.  If you remove that, your post is definitely more succinct and readable.

Comment: Using `imresize` the OP can also simply specify the desired length of the output vector rather than a scale factor using `B = imresize(A, [numrows numcols]) `

Comment: I've updated my answer. Thanks rayryeng, I'm so used to keeping to specified data types whenever working with image processing functions it never even occurred to me to try it with something else. 2cents, your comment was extremely helpful, thanks!

Comment: I didn't know you could use imresize for normal vectors as well. This is also perfect for what I'm doing. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Very nice.  This certainly deserves my upvote now.  Good job!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`linspace`](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linspace.html) to create linearly-spaced vectors with a fixed number of elements.

In your case, I would opt for a function handle based on `linspace` to perform this operation:

```
% --- Define the function handle
fun = @(A, n) linspace(min(A), max(A), n);

% --- Demo
A = 1:2:280;       % A has 140 elements
B = fun(A, 150);   % B has now 150 elements, with the same min and max
```

Best,

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this works indeed, but the elements in my vectors aren't necessarily linearly spaced between a min and a maximum.